# Django.fcgi using dynamic virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Is there a way to load the virtualenv in a dynamic way?

```
#!/home/root/.virtualenvs/production/bin/python

import os, sys
...
```

I'd like the path to be

`#!/home/root/.virtualenvs/production/bin/python` or `#!/home/root/.virtualenvs/staging/bin/python` depending if the folder name is `staging` or `production`

I can get the folder name this way:

```
_PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) 
sys.path.insert(0, _PROJECT_DIR) 
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(_PROJECT_DIR)) 

_FOLDER_NAME = _PROJECT_DIR.split('/')[-1]
```

But I have no idea if I can load the virtualenv in a dynamic way based on this.

It's a deployment issue, I currently have to replace the path in staging environment because it's hardcoded for production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using `env`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

And then run your application from the appropriate environment?

Comment: I don't quite understand what that does. Would the `python` binary change depending on the virtualenv I'm working with, dynamically? Like when doing  `source ~/.virtualenvs/staging/bin/activate`, and then `/usr/bin/env python` would be the python executable from the `staging` virtualenv?

Comment: `env` permits you to retrieve and launch the appropriate python interpreter according to the environment you're working in (it depends of the `$PATH` environment variable).
That's often used for scripts when you're not sure of the path of the interpreter on your system.

Comment: Then if you don't launch your script from a virtualenv it should use the system's interpreter and if you launch it from a virtualenv it should use the interpreter of this virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, looks like what I need indeed!

Comment: Well, I actually tried to use this today, and it didn't work. I believe it's because I'm using a very particular host provider, which doesn't use the virtual env the same way as I do when I call it manually. I haven't found any workaround so far. But I've read a lot of stuff around and your solution looks like the right way to do it.

Comment: @Vadorequest What does `which python` issue? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Well, I'm using a very particular hosting provider, which powers a server shared between different users/businesses. I'm not running Django myself, but I relaunch the process through their own GUI. I have no control regarding how the project is actually initialized, and my guess is that because of the way it's done, it doesn't select a virtualenv, and relies on a hard-coded one, specified by `#!/home/root/.virtualenvs/production/bin/python` in `public/django.fcgi`. So, my issue is somehow related to the fact that I don't have full control towards my hosting environment.